# Should you standardize a continuous outcome variable when using LASSO?

Tags: lasso, standardization

I'm running a LASSO regression on a continuous outcome, and am standardizing the features. Should I standardize the outcome as well?

Specifically I'm using the `glmnet` R package.

Comment: I have a response down but I'm not sure it is answering your question. Is your question more about what changes in the model, or what assumptions are required to standardize? Of course you always can standardize but that doesn't mean it is a good idea, one example where it would not help anything is on an outcome that is binary.

Answer (score 1):

From the glmnet doc:

> Note also that for
>   "gaussian"
>   ,
>   glmnet
>   standardizes y to have unit variance (using 1/n rather than
>   1/(n-1) formula) before computing its lambda sequence (and then unstandardizes the resulting co-
>   efficients);  if you wish to reproduce/compare results with other software,  best to supply a stan-
>   dardized y.

It depends on the distribution you are using/assuming as your response variable. If Gaussian or `mgaussian` in glmnet nomenclature, then you can center scale.

The answer of whether it makes any difference really depends on the outcome type. If the outcome is binary, the standardization will make no difference. If Gaussian there are some differences between standardized and non-standardized outcomes which are already handled by an argument into the `glmnet` function.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for best practice for a continuous/Gaussian `y`. Since it already standardizes by variance, it sounds like centering will only affect the intercept, is that right?

Comment: In the non-regularized case that is definitely true and should also be true in this case if the covariates are orthogonal. I'm not sure how that would impact things in highly correlated features. In that case you can observe some weird behavior, especially w/large number of features.